# UWP приложение вылетает при навигации назад с последней страницы Prism

Tags: uwp, prism

находясь на последней странице (в стеке навигации, т.е. дальше некуда возвращаться), при нажатии на аппаратную клавишу назад приложение, вместо того чтоб приостановиться, вылетает. Есть какой-то способ переопределить навигацию назад в приложении с MVVM Фреймворком Prims 6 ?

Answer (score 0):

Отменить и переопределить навигацию в Prism можно так:

```
deviceGestureService.GoBackRequested += (s, e) => 
{
    e.Handled = true;
    e.Cancel = true;
};
```

Но почему вы думаете, что приложение именно падает? Ведь это штатное поведение - закрывать приложение, если назад уже некуда.

Comment: хм, у меня штатное приложение ранее было такое, что оно сворачивалось и выходило на главный экран, а я мог вернуться в него. а тут оно полностью закрывается, это ужасно неудобно

Comment: и ответьте ещё на один вопрос, пожалуйста. есть ли обширная документация по UWP Prism ? А то я на гитхабе нашёл только для WPF и использую её, но ведь это не самый хороший вариант, ибо отличия существенные есть

Comment: не помогло, всё равно закрывается. хотя при навигации назад событие вызывается.

Comment: Какое именно приложение?
Свежей документации на русском  не видел, всё что надо беру тут https://github.com/PrismLibrary

Странно, что закрывается, не должно.

Comment: вы о чем " Какое именно приложение? " ?
так вот в том - то и дело, что странно. в отладчик ошибка не вылетает, поэтому это не исключение. а когда нужно подписываться на это событие ? я создал разделяемый класс App, наследуемый от PrismAutofacApplication, и там при активации подписываюсь на это событие. Но в отладчике шагал, оно заходит туда, и постоянно показывает, что стек навигации пустой. Использовал NavigationService

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, вам надо переопределить поведение приложения. Стандартное, что вы исследовали, сконфигурировано дабы сворачиваться при невозможности навигироваться назад. А ваше - на закрытие. Я не помню, как конкретно они конфигурируются, вы можете найти в справке и дополнить мой ответ